# Racket. Make a list of pairs from a list

Tags: racket

I want to make a list of pairs starting from a list, the cdr will be always the same. For example, `(make-pair '(1 2 3 4 5))` should return `'((1.a)(2.a)(3.a)(4.a)(5.a))`.

This is the code i am developing, but it doesn't work and I don't know how to debug it.

```
(define (make-pair lst)
 (if (null? (car lst))
      '()
      (cons ((car lst) ".a")
            (make-pair (cdr lst)))))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors:

```
(define (make-pair lst)
  (if (null? (car lst))      ; - the base case is when the list is null
      '()
      (cons ((car lst) ".a") ; - there's a missing cons
                             ; - `a` appears to be a symbol, not a string
                             ; - that's not how we create a dotted pair
                             ; - the surrounding `()` are misplaced
            (make-pair (cdr lst)))))
```

This is the right way:

```
(define (make-pair lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (cons (car lst) 'a)
            (make-pair (cdr lst)))))
```

Or even better, use built-in procedures:

```
(define (make-pair lst)
  (map (lambda (n) (cons n 'a))
       lst))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(make-pair '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '((1 . a) (2 . a) (3 . a) (4 . a) (5 . a))
```